# Mathematica: A way to set global NIntegrate options?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to be able to set a list of NIntegrate options globally (or somehow have to only write them once, and have them apply to a set of NIntegrate commands).  For example

```
WorkingPrecision -> 300, PrecisionGoal -> 5, Method ->{"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}
```

Sometimes when I am experimenting, the list gets much longer.  Is there a way I can do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this will do the trick:

```
SetOptions[NIntegrate, WorkingPrecision -> 300, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
 Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}]
```

See: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html

PS. You can post to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ next time. You might get a faster response.

Comment: oh!  I wasn't aware there was such a group.  Thanks!!